# Redux saga is is going to catch() instead of putting the action

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I have this action in `userActions.js`:

```
const receiveFilialData = (data) => {
    return {
        type: "RECEIVE_FILIAL_DATA",
        payload: data
    }
}

export default {
    receiveFilialData
}
```

In my login component, I'm making a dispatch to get some data from a saga:

```
const Login = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const filiais = useSelector(state => state.filiais)
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({type: 'GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST'})
  }, [dispatch, filiais])
}
```

In `LoginService.js` I'm making the HTTP request:

```
const fetchFiliais = async () => {
   const response = await fetch(`${baseUrlApi.baseUrlApi}/filiais`);
   const responseJson = await response.json()
   return responseJson
}

export default { 
    fetchFiliais
}
```

And I create a saga to make this request when there's a `GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST` dispatch:

```
// worker Saga: will be fired on GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST actions
function* fetchFiliais(action) {
    try {
        const data = yield call(LoginService.fetchFiliais())
        console.log(data)
        yield put({type: "RECEIVE_FILIAL_DATA", data});
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({type: 'FETCH_FILIAIS_FAILED', message: e.message})
    }
}

/*
  Starts fetchFiliais on each dispatched `GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST` action.
*/

function* mySaga() {
    yield takeEvery("GET_FILIAIS_REQUEST", fetchFiliais);
}
```

If I put a `console.log(response.json)` in the `LoginService` file, `fetchFiliais` is printing my response, but my `console.log(data)` after `yield call()` is not running; the control flow is going to `catch(e)` and throwing:

> type: "FETCH_FILIAIS_FAILED" message: "call: argument of type
>   {context, fn} has undefined or null `fn`"

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, putting `LoginService.fetchFiliais` instead `LoginService.fetchFiliais())`
This is not a function but a const